# Back button handling from a view in both present and push

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a UIViewControllerC which is call from two another UIViewcontroller

ViewControllerA
ViewControllerB

**From ViewControllerA to go to UIViewControllerC i have to make it presentviewcontroller**

```
 UIViewControllerC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UIViewControllerC"];
    [vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    vc.tagfrom=@"present";
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

**From ViewControllerB to go to UIViewControllerC i have to make it push view**

```
UIViewControllerC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UIViewControllerC"];
        [vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        vc.tagfrom=@"push";
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Now i have to back from both view on back button i check tagfrom condition and handle it

```
-(IBAction)backBtn:(id)sender
{
 if ([tagfrom isEqualToString:@"present"])
  {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
else
{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

}
```

**Which working fine in both senerio, but sometimes my push view behaves like presentmodelveiw, and having no transition effects in it, please help me to resolve it**

[image]

Comment: Downvote for what?

Comment: you can setModalTransitionStyle for presentViewController but not pushViewController

Comment: check case 1) to push and 2) to present view to a same view

Comment: remove [vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve]; for push view controller in Case 2(B to C)

Comment: No buddy....you don't get me....but thanks for Support

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "my push view behaves like presentmodelveiw, and having no transition effects in it"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `tagfrom` property on your `UIViewController` subclass.

A `UIViewController` instance has a property called `presentingViewController` which will let you know about the `viewController` ( **A in your case** ) that presented current `viewController` ( **C in your case** ).

```
-(IBAction)backBtn:(id)sender
{
   if (nil != self.presentingViewController) {
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
   }
   else {
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
}
```

Second, `modalTransitionStyle` is supposed to work with **only** `presentation` and **NOT** `push / pop` transitions. If you are using this with `push / pop`, the behavior is undefined because it is not meant to be used there.

Comment: up vote  for line->modalTransitionStyle is supposed to work with only presentation and NOT push / pop

Comment: @iphonemaclover bounty?